# The meaning of "skinny turkey tee's"

Tags: meaning

The phrase "SKINNY TURKEY TEE'S $10" in the image is supposed to be funny, but I can't figure out the reason. Could somebody explain why it's funny? Also, it's "TEE'S" instead of "TEES" - is it because it's the name of a company? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A "tee" is an abbreviation for a t-shirt.

In the image, the turkey on the left is wearing a t-shirt and the image printed on the t-shirt is of a skinny turkey body. So a 'Skinny Turkey Tee' is a t-shirt that has a skinny turkey printed on it.

The joke is that the turkeys are wearing the t-shirts in an attempt to look thin so that they won't get slaughtered for food at thanksgiving / Christmas.

As for "TEE'S" being the possessive - this is surely a mistake. I guess you don't have to be good at grammar to be a good cartoonist.

Comment: Many shops in the cheaper end of town use apostrophes in plural. It's even known as the greengrocer's apostrophe: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe#Superfluous_apostrophes_(%22greengrocers'_apostrophes%22)

Comment: @Sydney That's brilliant, I've never heard them called that before!

Comment: Thank you all for your explanations!